# Need some help with wiring a Shelly Plus 1 to fireplace

Tags: electrical, gas, fireplace, home-automation, relay

Trying to figure out how to wire up a Shelly Plus for Alexa control to turn on/off a gas ventless fireplace. Been reading this [guide](https://hometechhacker.com/wiring-the-shelly-plus-1-relay/#Shelly_fireplace_wiring) but I can't figure out how the gas valve gets wired. Here is my setup:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JKGJvBl.jpg]

I also have access to neutral and a hot connection via this board:



[image: https://i.imgur.com/cSKjVTF.jpg]

Couple questions:

1. should "main" or "pilot" be wired up to the Shelly Plus "1" or "0"?
2. how do I wire the Shelly Plus "SW" to the remote start connecter? Does it matter which "SWI" wire? There are two. I dont know what these connectors are called but they are the push type connectors

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a *ventless* gas fireplace in particular?  This seems like a compounding of bad ideas

Comment: I'm all for diy in many areas. Gas is not one of them. I suggest you have a professional install/configure this.